# User Synchronization SharePoint to AD

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

Is it possible to sync SharePoint user profile back to AD. I want users to be able to change there Job title which is mapped to an AD field. If they change it I want AD to show the change. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with 2010 it is possible to set the direction of the synchronization to either import or export which would allow you to support the use case of letting the users change the Job Title and then export it to AD.

To set it up, go into the User Profile Service Application and Manage Profile Properties.  At the very bottom where the synchronization mappings are, create an export mapping to the property you want to map it to.

As an added note, it is not advisable to have both an Import and an Export mapping in place for the same item.  This scenario is not fully supported and is likely to lead to problems.  It should be set to either import OR export, not both.

Comment: To add to Mike's advice, AD permissions for Export are spelled out in Spence's post: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx. By default Title is imported so you will need to change that to an export and then figure out how to initialize the field (if necessary).